# system2 output do not work within function

Tags: r

I have an executable (compiled FORTRAN) that uses the terminal to request input for the user and the output goes to different files (e.g., out1.txt, out2.txt). I have created an R function that generates a response file for the executable. Then I can use my response file to get all my output. For example if I run from the command line `pm.exe < pm.resp` I will get all my outputs (e.g., 1.txt, 2.txt, etc). Now I want to incorporate the whole procedure within R.

If I run from the R console `system2("pm.exe", wait = FALSE, invisible = FALSE, stdin = "pm.resp")` I get my output with no problem. However If use that line within an R function then I don't get any output.

Answer (score 0):

OK this may not help anyone but realize after a lot of pain what was the problem. The function that had `system2()` was part of a package I was building. Also, I was running a script that was loading a previous version of the function that did not have the `system2()` command. Because that function was in my global environment; it had precedence over the one created in the package.

If there is any morale about this... If your function is not behaving the way you expect. Check you are calling the right function.